# `git show` not working: "fatal: Path [mypath] exists on disk, but not in [mybranch]"

Tags: git

### Problem

I'm trying to view the contents of a file located in a branch named `wip` like so:

```
git show wip:local-config.php
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
fatal: Path 'local-config.php' exists on disk, but not in 'wip'.
```

### What I tried

I tried correcting the path but it failed:

```
git show wip:./local-config.php
```

Rather than using another branch, I tried to reference a previous commit from the same branch like so:

```
git show cd14704:local-config.php
```

That gave this error:

```
fatal: Path 'local-config.php' exists on disk, but not in 'cd14704'.
```

Finally when I try to show the current `local-config.php` I get no output at all:

```
git show local-config.php
```

### The docs

According to the manual this is possible: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `local-config.php` present in a commit within the `wip` branch? It sounds as though git is not tracking the file, or has only begun tracking the file in your current index, and there are no commits which contain the file.

Comment: wow, that was stupid on my part. You are right Chris, thank you for pointing that out. Add an answer and i'll upvote it.

Comment: You can do `git ls-tree wip` to see if there's a blob under a name of interest recorded in the tip commit of the branch "wip" without checking it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the file you're searching for does not exist in any commits within `wip`. `git show` will only display tracked objects with some history in the refspec you provide it (in this case, `wip`, or `cd14704`). To get the expected behavior you'll need a commit with that file present.

Answer (score 10):

I experienced exactly the same thing. The problem was that I used backslashes in my file path. So I replaced them by regular slashes and it started working just fine. Very confusing.

Comment: yep, my exact problem as well. I am on Windows using Git CMD and used tab key to specify path, it gave backslashes, replacing to forward slash fixed the problem. There was no problem in with Git Bash on Windows as tab key gives you forward slash.

Comment: Looks like I've come across this before - I see that I upvoted your answer at some point in the past. Thing is, the Git CLI usually accepts backslashes for Windows file paths. But not always...

Answer (score 7):

FYI, I got this same error when I was accidentally using the *full path* to the file:

```
git show rev:/path/to/repo-root/folder/my-file
```

But you need to use the *relative path* from the repo root:

```
git show rev:folder/my-file
```

Answer (score 2):

At least on Windows you'll get this message if you don't type the file path exactly right (letter case -wise).

So if the file name is `FileName` and you say `git show wip:filename`, you'll see this very message, because the file name matches in the underlying file system's (NTFS) comparison terms (case-insensitive, unless case case-sensitivity has been explicitly enabled in NTFS options), but not in Git's terms, because Git is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man git-show`, this is `git-show`'s syntax

`git show [<options>] [<object>...]`

`<object>` is

> The names of objects to show (defaults to HEAD).

Therefore, without any option, It will only show the files in the HEAD commit.

you can check files in the commit with

```
git show wip --name-only
```

There will be no file you search in the commit.

To show the file in its latest commit,

First, find the commits contain the file in the branch.

```bash
git log -n 1 <ref> <file>
# e.g
# git log -n 1 wip local-config.php
```

The result will be the latest commit contains the latest version of the file.

```bash
# example
commit 386389b0009e5750c1b27f690d97c1eec8b5fa44
Author: Author_name <email@email.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 1 07:12:17 2023 +0900
<commit message>
```

Then, get file content with `git-show`

```bash
git show 386389b0009e5750c1b27f690d97c1eec8b5fa44:local-config.php
```

This will print the content of the file of its latest commit.
Because `git-show` prints the content of the file in the commit, it won't print un-committed contents.